# Extract common part text from number of lines in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to extract common part of text from given number of lines.
Input:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/a/file1/dir
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/b/file2
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/c/file3/dir
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/a/file4
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/e/file5
```

Expected output is the common part from dir1 till dir4.
Sample expected output:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
```

What i have tried so far code:
pipe that input to awk command and then as belows

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i | sort | uniq -c -ne 1)var = i; break;}
```

But i am not able to get this working..I know i might have gone wrong on the logic or my understanding of the awk command. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: @fedorqui: the solution given in that post won't work as i don't want output as /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/a as the only part matching would be till dir4.. solution in that post will also give me strings matchin in the latter part of the string. the input above is the directory structure and i would want to maintain the same

Comment: OK. Reopened. However, that post can be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk to the rescue!

```
 awk -F/ 'NR==1{w=split($0,base,FS); next} 
               {for(i=1;i<=w;i++) 
                   if(base[i]!=$i) 
                       {w=i; next}
               } 
            END{for(i=1;i<w;i++) 
                   printf base[i] FS; 
                   print ""
               }' file
```

Description:  Construct a base array from the first line separated by FS, keep the size in w(for width). The match can be at most w.  For each line compare up to 2 fields until a mismatch occurs, update w.  When all done print the matching fields.

Comment: your solution worked like a charm. it would be better if you could also explain the code as i am novice to awk command.

Answer (score 3):

Perl solution for this longest-common-prefix problem

`perl -le '@a=<>; $p=$a[0]; for (@a){ chop $p while ! /^\Q$p/ }; print $p' file`

Constructs the array `@a` from the lines `<>` of the input file
`$p` is the longest prefix, which is initialized to the first element in the array `$a[0]`
Loop through the elements of array `@a`
While the prefix `$p` does not match `! //` the start `^` of the current element, `chop` off the last character.
`\Q` tells the regex engine to ignore any potential metacharacters
Finally, print the prefix `$p`

output:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
```

---

Alternate implementation using `-n` to implicitly construct the loop:

`perl -lne 'BEGIN{$p = <>}; chop $p while ! /^\Q$p/; END{print $p}' file`

---

Alternate implementation using `substr()` instead of `/regex/`

`perl -lne 'BEGIN{$p=<>} chop $p while $p ne substr($_,0,length($p)); END{print $p}' file`

`-n` loops over each line of the file
`$_` contains the current line contents

---

Alternate implementation using awk:

`awk 'NR==1{p=$0} {while(p != substr($0,1,length(p))){p=substr(p,1,length(p)-1)}} END{print p}' file`

---

Alternate implementation using Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
fp = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
p = fp.readline()
for line in fp:
    while (line.find(p) != 0):
        p = p[:-1]
print(p)
```

---

Alternate implementation using C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char p[MAXLINE];
    char line[MAXLINE];
    fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp);
    strcpy(p, line);
    while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp)) {
        while ( strstr(line, p) != line  &&  strlen(p) > 0 ) {
            p[strlen(p)-1] = '\0';
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", p);
}
```

---

Just for fun, I benchmarked the various solutions using a 20MB input file and 10 runs
My perl solutions are listed as a, b, c
Tested on perl 5.20 and 5.22
@karakfa's and my awk solutions are also listed, using awk 3.1.5 and gawk 4.1.0
@balabhi's shell solution is also listed
TL;DR:  The perl substr() solution (c) was the fastest among the scripting languages, but it doesn't matter which solution you use

```
                 Rate awk_karakfa gawk_karakfa perl_5.20_b perl_5.22_b perl_5.22_a perl_5.20_a   awk gawk python_3.4.2 shell_balabhi perl_5.22_c perl_5.20_c    c
awk_karakfa   0.618/s          --         -12%        -46%        -51%        -56%        -58%  -58% -80%         -81%          -82%        -85%        -86% -98%
gawk_karakfa  0.701/s         13%           --        -38%        -44%        -50%        -52%  -52% -77%         -79%          -80%        -83%        -84% -97%
perl_5.20_b    1.14/s         84%          62%          --        -10%        -19%        -22%  -22% -63%         -65%          -67%        -72%        -74% -96%
perl_5.22_b    1.26/s        104%          80%         11%          --        -11%        -13%  -13% -59%         -61%          -63%        -69%        -71% -95%
perl_5.22_a    1.41/s        128%         101%         24%         12%          --         -3%   -3% -55%         -57%          -59%        -65%        -68% -95%
perl_5.20_a    1.46/s        135%         108%         28%         15%          3%          --   -0% -53%         -55%          -58%        -64%        -67% -95%
awk            1.46/s        136%         108%         28%         15%          3%          0%    -- -53%         -55%          -58%        -64%        -67% -95%
gawk           3.11/s        402%         343%        173%        146%        120%        113%  113%   --          -5%          -10%        -23%        -30% -89%
python_3.4.2   3.27/s        428%         366%        187%        159%        131%        125%  124%   5%           --           -5%        -19%        -26% -88%
shell_balabhi  3.45/s        458%         392%        203%        173%        144%        137%  137%  11%           6%            --        -15%        -22% -88%
perl_5.22_c    4.05/s        555%         477%        256%        221%        187%        178%  178%  30%          24%           17%          --         -8% -85%
perl_5.20_c    4.41/s        612%         528%        287%        249%        212%        203%  202%  42%          35%           28%          9%          -- -84%
c              27.8/s       4392%        3861%       2342%       2100%       1867%       1808% 1806% 794%         750%          706%        586%        531%   --
```

Answer (score 1):

Submitting again as the indentation got messed up in last answer.
Bash script solution.

```
inf=$1
num=`wc -l $inf | awk '{print $1}'`
echo num=$num    
pfx=`sed -n '1p' $inf`
mat=`grep $pfx $inf | wc -l`
echo mat=$mat    
while [ $mat -ne $num ]    
do
    pfx=`dirname $pfx`/
    mat=`grep $pfx $inf | wc -l`
    echo mat=$mat    
done
echo pfx=$pfx
```

Comment: I benchmarked all of the solutions, and this was one of the fastest